# WPF: input duration (hh:mm:ss)

Tags: wpf, xamarin, mvvm

I would like to allow the user to enter a duration.
I want, if possible, to bind the input to an integer property which represents the value in seconds. The input should by formated like that: "HH:mm:ss".

I have this code in my ViewModel:

```
private int _duration;

public int duration
{
  get { return _duration; }
  set
  {
    if (_duration == value)
      return;
    _duration = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => duration);
  }
}
```

And my XAML:

```
<Textbox Text="{Binding duration, StringFormat=HH:mm:ss}"/>
```

But this doesn't work. I can enter any type of string (not only numeric) and the format is not respected.

PS: My project is a Xamarin Forms project, but I think it's the same thing.

Comment: Why an integer instead of `DateTime` ? Also, have you considered using a converter ?

Comment: My database format for this entry i `integer`. But I can use `DateTime` and convert it to `int` before saving it, that's not a problem. By the way, changing to `DateTime` doesn't change anything concerning the input formatting. I will try to write a converter and I will come back to give feedback.

Comment: `DateTime` + converter. Or even convert the integer value to the corresponding format for the UI. Both is possible with a proper converter.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TimeSpan` instead `int`( Howto : `TimeSpan.FormSecond(second)`).

VM:

```
void StartTimer(TimeSpan span)
{
    Duration = span;
    // Tick for each Seconds
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),()=>
    {
        Duration = Duration - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

        //return false when timer reachs 0
        return (Duration.TotalSeconds>0);

    });
}


Public TimeSpan Duration
{
  get{...}
  set{...}
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Label Text={Binding Duration, StringFormat='{0:HH:mm:ss}'} />
```

Comment: I got an error: `Input string was not in a correct format`. In you example, you use a Label, which is a readonly component. What I want is a writable component to allow the user to enter a duration.

Comment: wrong format. Sorry, my bad. Right format: `Text="{Binding Duration, StringFormat='{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}'}"`

Comment: Thank you. But even with this format, it allows to enter any character.